# click and if in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this function in my script :

```
$("#image4").click(function(){
   if($(this).attr("src")=="http://XXX.jpg"){
      $(this).attr("src","http://YYYY.jpg");
   }else{
      $(this).attr("src","http://XXX.jpg");
   } 
return false;});
```

HTML

```
<img src="http://XXX.jpg" id="image4"/>
```

I don't understand why when I click on my image, the if part doesn't works. I explain : If I use this code, nothing change. If I add and alert un my click function, I see the alert twice and see the image change twice to.
It seems, "if" doesn't works and apply "if" and "else" at each time

Someone can help me about that. I think it a basic feature, I don't understand why it doesn't works.

Thanks

Comment: console.log($(this).attr("src")) and see why it is not the same.

Comment: Your function syntax is not correct. Is that just a problem when copying to SO, or is that the way it is in the real code?

Comment: Do a little debugging and write the actual src-attribute to the console and compare it with your string. Maybe you attached it to the wrong DOM elememt, maybe your URL is wrong.

Comment: isn't `.click(function(){});`??

Comment: It is working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/pcX5C/

Comment: the code you posted does not reproduce the false behaviour you are explaining

Comment: Syntax error is correcting, sorry. It not explain my problem. I've made log and I see the two URL in log. It means, image change and come back.

Comment: @user1799879 - Are you able to recreate the problem at http://jsfiddle.net? (Because we can't: http://jsfiddle.net/MLRFd/) Or provide a link to your actual webpage where we can see it? As an aside, `$(this).attr('src')` is overkill: you can just get/set `this.src` directly.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, you're true. I will search an other cause.

Answer (score 6):

```
("#image4").click(function(){
                          ^^
```

you missed a bracket!

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/MAVyb/

Comment: Maybe you should wait for him to answer my comment that asked if that was just a copying error. I doubt it's the real problem, because then adding the `alert()` wouldn't have worked like he said it did.

Comment: it is the bracket... it is working otherwise

Comment: The OP has just edited in the (), so this no longer answers the question.

Comment: it is still working :)

Comment: see the fiddle... the `if`s are working, the alert box come only once, not twice,.. maybe mistake is somewhere totally else

Answer (score 0):

The sysntax and everything on your code is right so it is definetly value problem. Problem may be **src** have leading or trailing **space** in it.

try alert like

```
alert("-"+$(this).attr("src")+"-")
```

and whether is there any space between -(hypen) and src value.

also try

`alert(($(this).attr("src")=="http://XXX.jpg"))`, it should return **true** if the **src is equal**

**Update: i can reproduce your problem  -- you should have attached the event listener function for two times. check your original code. that is the problem. check your code. you can verify this by changing id to some other in jquery method and img tag**

Comment: What do you mean " you should have attached the event listener function for two times." I've only one click event on this id and one image with this id.

Comment: i tried many, but i can reproduce your problem with this code only   http://jsfiddle.net/ursgnanz/dYVEg/

Comment: if you are sure you have only one img tag , can you rename that img tag id to some thing "testimg", and attach event function to this . and check it

Comment: That is probably the right guess. I don't think it's a multiple id problem, though, it's definitely a double assignment of the `click()` handler. Maybe the script is executed twice for some reason.